# html: How to add line numbers to a source code block

Tags: html, css

I want to show source code with line numbers, in such a way that:

1. The code can be copied and pasted without the line numbers, respecting newlines, spaces and tabs.
2. The numbers are right-justified.
3. The code can wrap around.

I've tried the following approaches.

#### Ordered list

```
<style type="text/css">
    ol.code > li {
        white-space: pre-wrap;
    }
</style>
...
<ol class="code">
    <li>first line</li>
    <li>   indented line followed by empty line</li>
    <li></li>
    <li>the following line consists of one single space</li>
    <li> </li>
    <li>this line has a space at the end </li>
    <li>&#9;and one leading and ending tab&#9;</li>
    <li>fill to</li>
    <li>ten</li>
    <li>lines</li>
</ol>
```

This works for the most part, but when copying and pasting, the leading spaces and tabs in the lines are not copied in my browser (Iceweasel). So #1 fails with this approach.

#### Pre with counter

```
<style type="text/css">
    pre.code {
        white-space: pre-wrap;
    }
    pre.code:before {
        counter-reset: listing;
    }
    pre.code code {
        counter-increment: listing;
    }
    pre.code code:before {
        content: counter(listing) ". ";
        width: 8em;         /* doesn't work */
        padding-left: auto; /* doesn't work */
        margin-left: auto;  /* doesn't work */
        text-align: right;  /* doesn't work */
    }
</style>
...
<pre class="code">
<code>first line</code>
<code>   indented line followed by empty line</code>
<code></code>
<code>the following line consists of one single space</code>
<code> </code>
<code>this line has a space at the end </code>
<code>&#9;and one leading and ending tab&#9;</code>
<code>fill to</code>
<code>ten</code>
<code>lines</code>
</pre>
```

This almost works, but #2 fails. It has an additional problem that wrapped lines continue under the line number (next to the left margin), not under the line start (tabulated).

#### Sync lines and pre

This was a suggestion I found in https://www.sitepoint.com/best-practice-for-code-examples/ but it explicitly says that line wrapping must be disabled, therefore #3 fails. It also makes me very uneasy, as I've seen these blocks break in some sites.

Is there a way to do this **without JavaScript**?

Comment: Any reason you need to implement it yourself? https://github.com/google/code-prettify seems to do this and more

Comment: See what you can do with xmp tag.

Comment: @dave I've checked code-prettify now. It fails requisite #1 above (leading spaces, which are essential for Python, are lost on copy-paste) and the line numbers don't display correctly in my browser (only empty lines had a line number).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While technically my question is already answered by Rounin (thanks), truth is I was not fully satisfied with the result, because I didn't state a couple other requisites that I felt were important after posting the question, and they fail with that solution:

4. When a line wraps around, it should go underneath the above line, not underneath the line numbers.
5. Both the numbers and the text columns should be style-able (notably, the background of the whole column should be easily changeable).

I tried a solution with another `inline-block`, but it failed #5, and had problems with adjusting to any width.

`<OL>` was quite close, but not quite there. An alternative to `<OL>` that I knew wouldn't fly was to use a table. It wouldn't fly, because the browser *needs* a `<PRE>` element in order to copy/paste spaces and tabs properly.

Then all of a sudden, a solution clicked in my head. Forcing an element that is not a table to behave as if it was a table, is the exact purpose of the `table-xxxx` display values!

So here we go. Tested in Iceweasel 24.7.0 and Chromium 35.0.1916.153. The demo includes extra styling as an example of the versatility of the method.

The CSS:

```css
/* Bare bones style for the desired effect */
pre.code {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%; /* anything but auto, otherwise fixed layout not guaranteed */
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
pre.code::before {
    counter-reset: linenum;
}
pre.code span.tr {
    display: table-row;
    counter-increment: linenum;
}
pre.code span.th { /* used for line numbers */
    display: table-cell;
    user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}
pre.code span.th::before {
    content: counter(linenum);
    text-align: right;
    display: block;
}
pre.code span.th {
    width: 4em; /* or whatever the desired width of the numbers column is */
}
pre.code code {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

And the HTML:

```html
<pre class="code">
<span class="tr first-row"><span class="th"></span><code>   indented line</code></span>
<span class="tr"><span class="th"></span><code>unindented line</code></span>
<span class="tr"><span class="th"></span><code>&#9;line starting and ending with tab&#9;</code></span>
<span class="tr"><span class="th"></span><code></code></span>
<span class="tr"><span class="th"></span><code>the above line should be empty</code></span>
<span class="tr"><span class="th"></span><code>overlong line that wraps around or so I hope because it's really long and should overflow the right sided margin of the web page in your browser</code></span>
<span class="tr"><span class="th"></span><code>fill up to ten</code></span>
<span class="tr"><span class="th"></span><code>lines to check</code></span>
<span class="tr"><span class="th"></span><code>alignment</code></span>
<span class="tr"><span class="th"></span><code>of numbers</code></span>
</pre>
```

[Demo with extra styling](http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/temp/numbering-code-demo.html)

Update: Since I posted the question, learned that the GeSHi syntax highlighter has an option to use the following schema, which also meets all requisites and may be more acceptable to those that are allergic to tables:

```html
<ol>
  <li><pre>code</pre></li>
  <li><pre>code</pre></li>
  <li><pre>...</pre></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 30):

You need to add `display: inline-block` to your `::before` pseudo-element:

**eg.**

```
pre.code code::before {
  content: counter(listing) ". ";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8em;
  padding-left: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Then all your other styles will work.

---

**Explanation:** By default, `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements have a `display` style of `inline`.

You need to explicitly declare a `display` style of `block` or `inline-block` if you want to start setting `width`, `text-align` etc.

---

**Example:**

```css
pre.code {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
pre.code::before {
  counter-reset: listing;
}
pre.code code {
  counter-increment: listing;
}
pre.code code::before {
  content: counter(listing) ". ";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8em;         /* now works */
  padding-left: auto; /* now works */
  margin-left: auto;  /* now works */
  text-align: right;  /* now works */
}
```

```html
<pre class="code">
<code>first line</code>
<code>   indented line followed by empty line</code>
<code></code>
<code>the following line consists of one single space</code>
<code> </code>
<code>this line has a space at the end </code>
<code>&#9;and one leading and ending tab&#9;</code>
<code>fill to</code>
<code>ten</code>
<code>lines</code>
</pre>
```

---

**Added:** *An alternative CSS approach using `floats` and `clears` which means that when lines wrap, they do not wrap underneath the line number:*

```
pre.code {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  margin-left: 8em;
}

pre.code::before {
  counter-reset: listing;
}

pre.code code {
  counter-increment: listing;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}

pre.code code::before {
  content: counter(listing) ". ";
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 3em;
  padding-left: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! There's still the problem that wrapped lines go under the line number, rather than tabulated. Any hint on how to solve that?

Comment: I have added a slightly different CSS approach above, using floats and clears which means that lines which wrap will not start beneath the line number.

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't quite work as I expected, but I've managed to put something together using a separate `inline-block` for the text part as well (and `vertical-align` for the numbers part).

Comment: Three and a half years after writing the CSS above, I found I needed something similar to enable a button (for mobile browsers) which could display a web page's HTML Source on the screen (less fiddly to tap a button than prepending the URL in the URL bar with `view-source:`. See: [View HTML Source Button](https://rouninmedia.github.io/view-html-source-button/)

Comment: Without using `float`, there is a simple solution so text isn't wrapped under the line numbers. The trick is setting a margin on the code block and an equivalent negative margin on the line number. Example: add `pre.code code { margin-left: 4em; }` and `pre.code code::before { width: 4em; margin-left -4em; }` to @Rounin's first example. I also added alternating backgrounds to mine with `pre.code code:nth-child(2n+1) { background: white; }`. Looks and works great!

Comment: I used display: flex to help get the line number gutter to stretch the height of the wrapped line on the `pre.code code`

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using codemirror to do this instead of writing it yourself.

You get the functionality you describe for free and lots of other great stuff:

https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#usage

```
CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("myDiv"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    mode: "htmlmixed"
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use JS. I've edited the question to clarify that. Any hint on what HTML does that tool generate?

Comment: Hmmm, not really. I've not got an editor in front of me so I can't test this solution.

Comment: Hmmm, not really. I've not got an editor in front of me so I can't test this solution. Have you tried adding a nested span with a class  for the content of each code and then apply a margin-left to indent it?

Comment: I've looked into CodeMirror. While it does do what I have asked (except for the part of requiring JS), it's actually a full-fledged editor, too heavyweight for the purpose of just presenting snippets of code. It seems to rely on the underlying textarea for allowing text selection, so it actually needs two copies of the code. Scrolling needs JS active to work. It's not really what I was looking for, but thanks.

Comment: A more lightweight version is http://prismjs.com but I've not used it personally.

Comment: I don't see line numbering in prismjs. Maybe it's using features my browser doesn't support, or maybe it doesn't number lines. Either way, it's unsuitable too, unfortunately.

Comment: No worries, I hope you well with getting this solved. I understand you don't want to use a JavaScript library however for anyone who is,  they do have a plug in for line numbers too. http://prismjs.com/plugins/line-numbers

Comment: Ah, I see now. I couldn't get lines to wrap around, so it fails requisite #3. It seems to use the trick in the page I linked.